# connect my android app with other websites for runtime search and update

Tags: android

I want to create an app like cleartrip or any other flight booking app. But i want to know how can i access the details of flights from respective airlines in such a way that if a ticket is booked from my app then it should also be affect the particular airlines website. Or if a ticket is booked in the respective airlines website the it should also affect in my app. I want to know the logic of how to make my app work in sync with airlines. can i achieve this with the help of api of respective airlines?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use a service that provides you the API for all airlines. One of the examples is [Travelport API](https://developer.travelport.com/app/developer-network/universal-api).

The API can help you get all the details for airlines and also enable you to book tickets. You'll need to pay them for the API usage and also need to get well acquainted with their docs in order to use the API.

Comment: using the api of particular airline can i update the database of that airline when ever a ticket is booked through my app?

Comment: If travelport allows you to book tickets with some airline, it should be indirectly adding entries in the airlines database.